# building openssl for ARM

Tags: gcc, openssl, arm, cross-platform, libwebsockets

I am trying to build openSSL for my embedded board with ARM M4 running with a POSIX compliant OS (MQX). What I need is to build a libwebsocket library with openSSL support for the same environment.
So what I am getting from all the web is openssl cross compilation for linux specifically. see below link...which is using linux patch.
https://how-to-build-for-arm.wikispaces.com/openssl

while some resources I found are for cyaSSL for ARM.

Can anyone please guide me how should I look into this?

I have basic knowledge of library and building it. apart from following online instruction I don't have any hard core experience with it.

Thank you.

Comment: The gist of the linked page is "configure it; build it", which is not particularly noteworthy. A couple of 3-year-old patches merely tweaking some makefile dependencies and documentation formatting can probably be safely ignored, but are hardly "Linux patches" either way. What's the specific problem you're having?

Comment: I am using atollic IDE and gcc for my project.
My target machine:ARM M4
My host machine:win 7 pc, i686 (which is I think causing me some confusion)
I am trying to follow the instruction from the linked page (modifying some settings)
note: I am using cygwin here. and after reaching to some configuration, it is showing me the error of no make command.
I am processing all the commands in openSSL extracted directory which has the parent makefile.
Can you guide me with some points how should I carry out this building of openssl for ARM using gcc so that to make it able to cross compile.

Comment: so main problem I am facing is while following the link when I am looking at the comment for the patches of linux...
the same about my target which is running on MQX I am not getting...
any idea how to tweak that??